# Drop object in specific index (place) in listBox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have 2 list boxes and I'm dragging objects from the first listBox to the second.
I s there anyway to drop the object in a specific place in the second one (with a small line or something so i can see where is it going to be dropped)?

This is my code, it contains Home.Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My_Tool.Pages.Home"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Pages/Styles/ListBox.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Pages/Styles/LightListBox.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="120"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lbOne" Margin="{StaticResource SplitLeft}"
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleListBox}"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />
        <ListBox x:Name="lbTwo" Grid.Column="2 " Margin="{StaticResource SplitRight}"
                 Drop="ListBox_Drop" AllowDrop="True"
                 Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleLightListBox}"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the Home.cs:

```
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list.Add(new My_Data("first", "explanation"));
            list.Add(new My_Data("second", "explanation"));
            list.Add(new My_Data("third", "explanation"));
            list.Add(new My_Data("forth", "explanation"));
            list.Add(new My_Data("fifth", "explanation"));

            lbOne.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        ListBox dragSource = null;
        private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
            dragSource = parent;
            object data = GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, e.GetPosition(parent));

            if (data != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
        #region GetDataFromListBox(ListBox,Point)
        private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
        {
            UIElement element = source.InputHitTest(point) as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
                    if (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                    {
                        element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
                    }
                    if (element == source)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    return data;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion

        private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
            object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(My_Data));
            //((IList)dragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);
            parent.Items.Add(data);
            //Console.WriteLine(parent.Items.GetItemAt(counter).ToString());
            My_Data asd = (My_Data)parent.Items.GetItemAt(counter);
            asd.Number_pic = @"C:\Pages\Styles\icon-"+(counter+1)+".png";
            counter++;
        }


    }

}
```

ListBox.xaml and LighListBox.xaml are just design to the objects in the list.

Thanks all!!

Comment: `list` needs to be `ObservableCollection<My_Data>` if it isn't already. Then you can add, remove, or reorder items in the collection and the ListBox will reflect that. For the visual indicator in the list items, you want to add a dependency property `bool IsDragging` to your usercontrol, and give the ListBox an ItemContainerStyle with a trigger that sets a borderbrush and borderthickness="0,2,0,0" for the item when a) IsMouseOver **and** b) usercontrol IsDragging. Then finally a style trigger on the ListBox to show a visual indicator on drag after the last item. How much of that makes sense?

Comment: Oh i forgot to paste this line to here... but yes, it is ObservableCollection<My_Data>. For now it works great. but it's dropping automatically at the last place of the second ListBox... I'm not sure i understood you 100% percent good, but i will try to implement it.

Comment: Right, you're *adding* it to the end of the collection. You need to insert it in front of the item it was dropped on.

Comment: I succeeded inserting the object in front of the item it was dropped on... but still i didn't understand how to add a preview line... (visual indicator).

Comment: I know two good ways to do a visual drop-target indicator in a WPF ListBox (could think of a few bad ones too): Either an adorner, or by setting an attached property flag on the child ListBoxItem that's the drop "target" and having the ItemContainerStyle show a border overlay. [Here's an example I recently wrote that does it with an Adorner](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2017/12/07/dragdroplistbox/).